# Crypto JS equivalent of Java encryption method?

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, cryptojs

I am trying to translate a backend encryption method that is written in Java into CryptoJS.

Here is the backend Java Method that I am trying to copy using CryptoJS, If I use the decrypt method with my encoded string outputted from my CryptoJS function it is not the expected result:

```
private static final String ALGORITHM="PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
private static final String TRANSFORMATION="AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static final String ALGO_NAME="AES";


  public String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
    try {
      byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
      IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
 
      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
      SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGO_NAME);
 
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
      return Base64.getEncoder()
          .encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }
  

  public String decrypt(final String strToDecrypt) {
    try {
      byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
      IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
 
      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
      SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGO_NAME);
 
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
      return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And here is my attempt at using CryptoJS to mimic the encryption method. When I use the decryption method with the output from my CryptoJS function, it is not the expected result.

```
const aes = async () => {
// -- AES ------------------------------------------------------------- //

var key1 = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("key", "salt", 65536, 256);

const text = `{"company":"1","currency":"GBP","amount":"20","title":"Test"}`;
const iv = Buffer.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

const encryptedStr = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key1, {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
});

var plaintext = encryptedStr.toString(CryptoJS.enc.utf8);
console.log(plaintext);
};
```

For security reason I can't post the actual Key and Salt. I basically want the CryptoJS function to do exactly what the Java method is doing so when I use the Java decrypt method my result is the same as if I took the output from the encrypt method.

Comment: Key size and iteration count are passed incorrectly (see CryptoJS docs). Furthermore, CryptoJS applies SHA1 by default for PBKDF2.

Comment: Hi, you got any solution for this? I am also look for solution.